# All Unit Test from test explorer run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022

I've got some issue when working with unit tests in C# in Test Explorer From Visual Studio 2022. When I marked one group/test by clicking in it, then using right mouse button -> Run/Debug VS running all test instead of only marked. Some times ago it run correctly.

I think, that is maybe version of VS error but when update to latest (17.5.5) error still occured.

Thank you all.

Comment: Make sure you also don't have the test project itself selected in the text explorer window.  If you do, it will run all the tests in the project regardless of the other ones you have selected.  Aside from this, I can't reproduce this.